# Ошибка при работе с регулярными выражениями

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Вобщем есть регулярное выражение:

```
private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/^ds\\.notify\\.([a-z]*)\\./i");
```

им я пытаюсь из  строки такого   `ds.notify.change.otherText`   вытащить слово `change` но `matcher` почему то не находит, попробовал на http://regexr.com/ проверить -  там все норм. В чем может быть проблема?

```
if (!matcher.find()) {
    throw new Exception("..");
}

path = matcher.group(1);//base group
```

Comment: Что значит вытащить change, взять все без него или только его?

Comment: `private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)^ds\\.notify\\.([a-z]*)\\.");`. Это не JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В начале лишний `/`, и в конце не добавляется модификатор видимости `/i`:

```
private final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^ds\\.notify\\.([a-z]*)\\.");
```

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, не видел комментария, но и без этого флага все будет работать в данном примере,  весь вопрос в том какой именно флаг нужен и нужен ли он вообще. Может быть строка вида ds.notify.CHANGE.otherText является ошибочной и это как-то нужно обрабатывать.

Comment: А комментарий взяли и удалили...

Comment: Если бы я удалил свой комментарий после появления отклика на него – это нехорошо, да, а удаление комментария до появления ответа на него – вполне нормально. А флаг `i` в **данной конкретной задаче** на самом деле излишен. Но все-таки в ответе, я считаю, следовало бы указать правильный способ задания флагов.

Comment: Этот пример рабочий, а каким образом можно сделать так что бы выражение игнорировало регистр символов.